# How to get rid of the hitch when lazy loading pages of a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiscrollview

I tried to implement the lazy loading solution for `UIScrollView` with paging enabled, as in the *PageControl* example from Apple. It seems to work fine, the only problem is that as the user scrolls past the 50% of the page, there is this short hitch as the content of the next page is loaded (obviously because loading the next ViewController takes some time and it seems to happen on the main thread).

Is there some way to make the scrolling seem more smooth that would work no matter how fast the user scrolls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that anything which takes time happens asynchronously.  The techniques for this will vary based on what kind of content you're loading or what sort of drawing you're doing that causes the delays.  Try to load images in the background, do custom drawing in the background, use operations or gcd to break up large tasks into smaller chunks that can happen concurrently, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be lazy loading the surrounding pages so that they're already loaded when the user scrolls.

So if the user scrolls to page 2, load pages 1 and 3 (if they aren't already)

Comment: that's what i'm doing, but there's a hitch when i'm loading the page 3 as the user scrolls to the middle of the page 2

Comment: This will suffer the same problems, just that when you scroll the hitch will happen loading page N+2 instead of N+1.